# Cannot locate bluetooth drivers for Dell Studio 1558 on their website

Tags: windows, bluetooth, drivers

I visited the Dell website but couldn't find the drivers.

Can anyone give me the link to download bluetooth drivers for a Dell Studio 1558?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7, this should be it : [Dell Wireless 365 Bluetooth Module](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R226746&SystemID=STUDIO1558&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=16167&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=5&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=325097).